# how do you make buttons flash or blink different colours in android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am creating a tic tac toe program. I can get the buttons to display an X or 0 but I can't get them to display different colours. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a selector to change button color when clicked.

`/res/drawable/btn_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffaa66"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffdd99"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

And now apply this xml as `android:background` to the button.